# Dualcore vs Quadcore for Development

Tags: development-environment

Recently I am thinking to upgrade my current development laptop in newer machine. I'm all the while working under Linux/Windows dual boot and doing development work on both.

My current development platform including Java (Eclipse), Ruby/RoR (Gvim/Atom), Blender (learning), Erlang, ANSI C (VS/gcc), Android Studio for Android development, VirtualBox running Windows for Microsoft Office suite, C# development and MSSQL development. Sometimes need to debug as well under Virtualbox Windows by running Eclipse. Natively on Linux using MySQL/Postgresql for development and testing. I'm interested in exploring 3D and game programming as well.

Occasionally I do play some 3D games on Windows such as Modern Warfare 4, BF4 etc.

Now for the new year, thinking to upgrade to Macbook Pro but I'm undecided on to look at dualcore or should I stick to quadcore? Is there any benefit if I'm using quadcore for development purposes?

Googled and found the link below but it is done in year 2007.

http://blog.codinghorror.com/choosing-dual-or-quad-core/

http://blog.codinghorror.com/quad-core-desktops-and-diminishing-returns/

Understanding that utilizing multiple cores is mostly software or OS responsibility and this is easier to update to utilize those extra fire power.

So is it still trivial for development machine to have quadcore CPU as of 2015/2016? I've already targeted I'd take 16GB of RAM but not on CPU choice.

Comment: What, exactly, is the answer to this question going to help you to learn?

Comment: Sorry should I move it to another forum instead? I asked here simply here has the best developer mind in the world which my perspective on this mainly come from developer.

Comment: I could move it to other forum if this does not seems to bother most of the developer that much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for an upgrade I would recommend you to first look for a laptop that comes with a SSD harddisk because disk I/O is the typical performance bottleneck.

As for whether you should go for dual or quad cores... I personally think it doesn't really matter because not every piece of software is written to fully utilizes all CPU cores. It really depends on how the software is implemented. For instance if it is a multi-threaded or multi-process program then you will benefit heavily otherwise you probably won't see much of a difference. But the speed of your CPU core will definitely make a difference thou.

I see so you are also into games programming and some serious FPS gaming like BF4, then you will definitely need a powerful quad chipset and also an excellence graphics card. Otherwise if it is just for pure web/server development (not games), a good dual core should do it.

Comment: However some of the statistic saying multi core CPU does not really change the CPU operation model that much on gaming, i.e. dualcore and quadcore does not show significant difference between those. Understand the multi core CPU much to do with rendering graphics etc. Just wondering it makes different too in software development.

Comment: Do you mind elaborating on what a CPU operation model is? Do you mean performance? If yes then true. Not all games will benefit from your quad cores, as i mentioned earlier this is mainly because of how the game is implemented. A simple single threaded game like tic tac toe will not benefit from your 4 cores while CPU intensive games like BF4 which is highly very likely to be multi-threaded so u will benefit from it.

Comment: Generally I tried not to use performance that much as it is hard to compare apple to apple on performance per se as different CPU has different clock speed, cache etc. I generally use operation model to describe what comes out from the CPU operation/output of the game. It might be just me to think that.

Comment: Ok. Hope I did help you in some way hahaha good luck in shopping your next machine, you probably can get a good deal since its xmas season!

Comment: You did, thanks! Merry Christmas!

Comment: Just an update on an observation:
While I was experimenting with JavaFX recently, I notice all my cores hit 90% and above before the GUI is shown and drop back to normal after the GUI is shown. I think new component starting to use all the cores available for its operation.
From this, it would be a positive confirmation getting more cores is indeed desirable for development laptop.